# Integrating the ActiveX attachment manager from iNotes with an XPage

Tags: activex, attachment, xpages

Does anybody have experience binding the ActiveX attachment from iNotes to a rich text field in an XPage? I'm specifically looking for any pitfalls you've encountered, but any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest my webDAV implementation - works like a charm. Some rough edges (anybody willing to do a plug-in with < 200 lines of C?)

Comment: Stephan, can you point me to that implementation? Not sure WebDAV will meet our needs, but I'm sure somebody here is smart enough to adapt it. :)

Comment: On OpenNTF soon. PM for a preview

Comment: Can we start putting these suggestions in answers instead of comments so that these questions stop showing up as unanswered, please?